# How is memory usage structured in JavaFX?

Tags: performance, memory-management, javafx

I'm programming an application with Java FX, which can display big images (about 10 000 × 10 000 pixels big). The Image is displayed in a scrollPane. (With the image view class)
To get a relative low memory usage I raster the image into a big amount of single images. (A amount of imagw viewers in a group placed into a scroll pane) So as result the parts of the images are placed in a row in the scrollPane. Goal is, that the images, which aren't in the viewport area, will be unloaded. I know, that I can unload nodes. But I don't know whether the images get unload and remain in memory or whether they get removed from memory.

My question is:
 Are the images, which are declared over the image class of java fx, loaded at initialization into the memory or get they loaded if they are needed ?

My idea is to set the image in the image view object to null. (ImageView.setImage (null))

I hope my text isn't as that confusing.

Edit:
I know, that performance will drop, if images will be unloaded dynamically.

Edit:

It's JVM Memory meant. Not native Memory

Comment: Perhaps you might want to base your implementation upon a ControlsFX [GridView](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html), rather than creating it all from scratch.  "the number of GridCell instances instantiated will be a significantly smaller number than the number of items in the GridView items list, as only enough GridCells are created for the visible area of the GridView. This helps to improve performance and reduce memory consumption."

Comment: @jewelsea Thx, that's a great Idea. In fact this is doing what my Programm I've written does. But U thunk; that the Oracle implementation is better because it could be more native. I don't know. I'll try to find out !

Answer (score 2):

From the question alone it is unclear what is meant by "memory", as there is **JVM memory** and **native memory**. You can reduce native memory usage by tuning JVM settings. As for JVM memory, generally speaking, any object that you lose a strong reference to will still remain in memory because of [how garbage collection works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/). It may even be in memory until the application process finishes.

In addition, here's some numbers that might help:

10 000 * 10 000 * 4 / (1024 * 1024) =~ 381 MB (based on how image is stored, you can explore `com.sun.prism` package for more information).

So when you load a single unscaled image with specified size, JVM will allocate at least that amount of memory for the image alone, not to mention a great deal of other things. As such there is no clear deterministic way of removing data from memory. Therefore, it is important to **allocate less memory in the first place** if low native memory usage is required. You can do so with [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.io.InputStream-double-double-boolean-boolean-) `Image` constructor, which will scale image as necessary if you are not planning to show the image immediately. It is worth pointing out that once JVM has claimed a piece of memory, it rarely gives it back to native memory.

Comment: I used programs to view images with this size and with 4 gb of RAM but at least all of them closed. I thought of the cause and the result is the image size. As well I thought, that with Java I still will have this problem.

Comment: As JavaFX is, by default, hardware rendering based, the gating factor on Image size in JavaFX is neither available system memory nor JVM memory, but is instead the limit of the maximum texture size of the graphics hardware being used (which for midrange modern GPUs, is currently around 8192x8192).